# Running a C++ Console Program in full screen

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to run a C++ Console Program in full screen ? , using VS2008

Comment: Why don't you set the dimensions of your output window ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just tested this with `cl fullscreen.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

int main()
{
    ::SendMessage(::GetConsoleWindow(), WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0x20000000);

    std::cout << "Hello world from full screen app!" << std::endl; 
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Unfortunatelly it had duplicated the text on the second monitor :)

Comment: Thanks this works but Windows 7 doesn't support to make a cmd window full-screen !

Comment: If you literally want full screen this is good, but in most cases you'll want windowed full screen.

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
system("mode 650");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvote because it works for me! Combine   ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);  for even better result - maximize window.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <windows.h>

SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE,0);
```

Comment: If you literally want full screen this is good, but in most cases you'll want windowed full screen.

Answer (score 3):

There are not a lot of video adapters around these days that still support this.  Run cmd.exe and press Alt+Enter.  If you get a message box that says "This system does not support fullscreen mode" then you're done.  If it does switch to full screen then you can use SetConsoleDisplayMode() in your main() function.  Of course, you don't know what your customer's machine is like, best not to pursue this.

Answer (score 3):

That's what I'm using:

```
system("mode con COLS=700");
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),SW_MAXIMIZE);
SendMessage(GetConsoleWindow(),WM_SYSKEYDOWN,VK_RETURN,0x20000000);
```

It removes the scrollbar :D

Answer (score 2):

For full screen windowed mode: `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);`

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround: You could use some sort of earlier DOS video modi, for example...

```
asm
{
    mov     ax, 13h
    push    bp
    int     10h
    pop     bp
}
```

...to have a resolution of 320x200 pixels.

But I'm not sure if this would work for a windows application... Probably not!

Comment: No, it won't work for window's applications. It will only work on DOS, in real mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line (anywhere) before your output,

```
system("mode 650");
```

Such as,

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    system("mode 650");
    cout<<"Hey, this words are shown in full screen console! "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```